# How to vertically align divs with dynamic sizes?

Tags: html, css

I have a series of div's whose heights will be dynamically generated based on the content inside them. Right now I'm able to align them horizontally using `float: left` but as soon as the div's go onto the next line, there is white space in between the divs that don't have matching heights. Here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

[image: Vertically aligned divs]

Oh and I'm looking for a pure CSS solution. The project I'm currently working on is archaic and I can't use any new frameworks on it.

Comment: you can achieve it by using display table element...what browsers do you need to support?

Comment: ie8-ie11, chrome, ff, safari.

Comment: foundation and bootstrap require IE 9+....so their framework cannot be used, try finding framework that supports IE 8+

Answer (score 0):

Can you please be more specific or upload the code. If you want a grid layout then go for Bootstrap. It's the best framework for responsive and grid layout !

Comment: ah yeah if I could use a modern framework like Bootstrap I would but I can't :(

Comment: Bro, bootstrap layouts are purely css. You can use them. No Js Required for just using the layouts. [link](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css)

Comment: Thanks bro. I'll look into it

Comment: Mean while let me get an easy approach for you :)

Answer (score 0):

**Original Post can't use Bootstrap, but just in case you can**

This might be a silly answer but you can just use columns within a framework like [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) or [Bootstrap](http://www.getbootstrap.com).

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div style="height: 300px; border: 1px solid red;"></div>
            <div style="height: 300px; border: 1px solid red;"></div>
            <div style="height: 600px; border: 1px solid red;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div style="height: 300px; border: 1px solid red;"></div>
            <div style="height: 600px; border: 1px solid red;"></div>
            <div style="height: 300px; border: 1px solid red;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div style="height: 600px; border: 1px solid red;"></div>
            <div style="height: 300px; border: 1px solid red;"></div>
            <div style="height: 300px; border: 1px solid red;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And your fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/sg2787ft/

Comment: Can't use bootstrap or any modern framework :( looking for a pure CSS solution.

Comment: Please note in fiddle I changed the column to .col-sm-4 and not .col-md-4 -- this was just because the window size in the fiddle was stacking the columns as though they were on a mobile device.

Comment: Just create a class called column-third that is width 33.333333333333% (just like Bootstrap), then make them display: block & width: 100% on a certain media query. Following me?